# Class not found error on creating a custom service inside a module

Tags: 8

I want to create a class with list of helper functions, so I created a module and placed the helper functions inside it. I created a service.yml inside that module folder.

```
services:
  helpers.helpers:
    class: Helpers
```

Helper class file:

```
class Helpers {
   public function buildPage($page_template, $template_variables) {
      echo "Dheivamey oru vazhiya"
   }
}
```

I make it as a dependency inside another module.

```
dependencies:
  - helpers:helpers
```

I tried using it inside a controller file like this

```
public function buildSomePage(Request $request) {
  $helper = \Drupal::service('helpers.helpers');
}
```

But I am getting a **Helpers class not found error**. Someone help me before my head explode.

Comment: The path to your class in the service definition is incorrect. It needs to be the full path to the class under the \Drupal namespace. Is this all of the code? If so you’re missing more. Check the documentation for creating service objects. Besides that, your controller should be injecting dependencies, instead of use \Drupal::service.

Comment: I used the namespace namespace Drupal\module_name\Service, but still it showed the same error, so thats why I tried removing namespace

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved after I included the full namespace from Drupal\module-name and placed the file inside the src folder. I included the namespace earlier, but I missed placing the corresponding "Helper" file in the src directory.

Comment: Meanwhile if we want to use service using dependancy injection, (**of course a suggested best practice**) we have to override the static create function as mentioned [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/drupal-8-properly-injecting-dependencies-using-di--cms-26314).